# How to make a sidebar item behave like a file explorer button in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I have a sidebar with Routing functionality.
For one of the items on the sidebar, I want it to open the file explorer menu upon clicking.
However because of the Routing I am not able to put the file explorer syntax

```
<input type = "file", name = "file", onChange = {{selectFileHandler}} />
```

Below are the snippets of my application :

SidebarItems.js

```
const SidebarItems = [
    {

    {
        name: "Page 1",
        route: '/'
    },
    {
        name: "Load-File",
        route: '/loadfile'
    },

];

export default SidebarItems;
```

Sidebar.js

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  
  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
        <Nav>
          <NavIcon to="#">
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </NavIcon>
          <h1>
            My page
          </h1>
        </Nav>
        <nav>
        
          <ul className='nae-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return( <li key={index}   />
               <Lint to={item.route}>
               <span>{item.name}</span>
                );
            })}
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
  
export default Sidebar;
```

And the Routes.js:

```
function Routes() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Page1}/>
                <Route path="/loadfile" component={loadfile}/>
               
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

How can I modify the loadfile part in the Router to make it behave like a button which will directly open the file explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not straightforward, but here's a rough hacked-together demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bush-0s6l6

If you click 'Toggle' it mounts a `<FilePickOpener />` which should automatically open the dialog:

```
const FilePickOpener = () => {
  const inputFileRef = useRef(null);
  const onClick = () => {
    inputFileRef.current.click();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    inputFileRef?.current && inputFileRef.current.click();
  }, [inputFileRef]);

  return (
    <form style={{ visibility: "collapse" }}>
      <input type="file" ref={inputFileRef} />
      <button onClick={onClick}></button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

**Disclaimer**: I've only tested on Chrome, it may or may not work on other browsers. Buyer beware.

**Update**: As feared, it won't work on Safari. Probably a security feature requiring an actual click to initiate.

Comment: Where should I include this part of the code ? In the loadfile.js ?  which is redirected by  <Route path="/loadfile" component={loadfile}/> ?

Comment: So this could be your `loadfile` component (btw, component names should be Capitialized)

Comment: It is working, but useEffect can't be used in a class Component. how can I handle that part. Using React.createRef  I have taken care of the inputFileRef amd the onClick. But not able to use useEffect. Please help!

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast Why do you have to use a class component?

Comment: Well, the Loadfile component is actually redirecting it to a new page with the route path /loadfile. I want to access whatever file is selected in Loadfile, that file to be accessed from the other Route (exact component , Page1). Also I want once the file is selected , the page to be redirected to Page1. Because of all these, I have now changed the Load-File route path to Page1 only. Page1 is already a class component. Hence I am doing this way. Please suggest a better way.  I am new to React. Thanks